# Perl Regular Expression | How to read a string from a file using

Tags: regex, string, file, perl

I'm working on a new project that uses Perl Regular Expression and I'm searching a way to retrieve text from a local-file using a one-line Perl Regular pattern.

I want the regular expression to be in a one line form and note to a coding one like :

```
         ^(?!.....(?:........)).*$
```

I don't want to have a "code-like" form like:

```
       use warnings;
       use strict;
       use feature qw(say);

       use Path::Tiny;
       my $file = shift // die "Usage: $0 file\n";  #/
       my @words = split ' ', path($file)->slurp;
       my $exclude = join '|', map { quotemeta } @words;
       foreach my $string (qw(a1testtre orangesh1 apleship3)) 
       { 
           ........
           ........ 
           }
        }
```

My final goal is to search (**with one-line Perl regex !!**) the strings of a  txt file and then check if one of them are part of a the string that I'm testing. 
So far i have create a Perl Regular Expression

```
  ->        ^(?!.*(?:banned)).*$
```

that check if the string that I'm testing contains the word "banned" inside it.

See example here: https://regex101.com/r/toQpCb/1

now if i can with some way replace the "banned" world with the content of the local file (txt) that i want i will be ready. A suitable solution could be something like:

```
    ^(?!.*(?:\someway_the_string_from_me_local_txt_file\)).*$
```

Comment: Why can't you do `perl -nE 'BEGIN{open $FH, "<", "file.txt"; $ex = join "|", map { quotemeta } split " ", <$FH>;}say "OK" if /^(?!.*(?:$ex)).*$/` or something like that? I can't see any good reason to compact everything inside the regex. Don't think that "one-liner" == "single regex".

Answer (score 1):

You want to check that every position isn't the start of one of your words, so you actually want

```
^(?:(?!WORD1|WORD2|...).)*\z
```

so

```
my $good_re = qr/^(?:(?!$exclude).)*\z/s;

if ($string =~ $good_re) {
   # Good
} else {
   # Bad
}
```

But instead of checking if the string is "safe", it's more efficient to check if it's unsafe (then simply invert the result).

```
my $bad_re = qr/$exclude/;

if ($string =~ $bad_re) {
   # Bad
} else {
   # Good
}
```

Comment: yes but my big problem is to find a way how to read the content of a local file (.txt) using a one-line perl Regex. If i find that then the difficult part of my problem is over. For example if i have a txt in path [ C:/data.txt ] that contains the word "banned" and i can read it and use it my problem solved by 90%

Comment: A regex pattern defines a set of strings, and a regex match operator checks if a string is in a set of strings defined by a regex pattern. Neither reads files. You'll have to continue reading the files outside of the match as you are currently doing.

Comment: So there is no way to read content from file using a regex pattern?